# can't read property "length" of undefined in jade

Tags: json, pug

```html
table
      tbody
        tr
          th ID
          th Product Name
          th Price
          th Category
          th Action
        if data.length
         each item in data
          tr
            td #{item['_id']}
            td #{item['product_name']}
            td #{item['price']}
            td #{item['category']}
            td
```

For this code I'm getting error **can't read property 'length' of type undefined**

[image: for this code i m getting error**cant read property 'length' of type undefined**]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use if data which will do the same thing your doing now, testing if the data is not empty.